# Coupling Inductor

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, inductor, emc

I read a paper about EMI in switching power supply from CPES.

This is the paper name "Common Mode EMI Noise Reduction Techniques in Switch Mode Power Supplies"

In the context I am confused about below description:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Below are my questions:

1. Why figure 4-8 cam transfer to figure 4-9
2. What does equivalent decoupled circuit mean.
3. How to derive the equation from figure 4-9.